# D3 selective Zoom

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming, force-layout

I am working on a force directed graph layout with some added features: selectable links/nodes, tooltips, fisheye effect, and -- important for my question -- zoom and pan.

Now, the zooming works very well like this:

```
d3 ... .append('svg:g').call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw))...
```

Where the redraw function looks like this...

```
function redraw() {
  trans = d3.event.translate;
  scale = d3.event.scale;
  vis.attr("transform", "translate(" + trans + ")" + " scale(" + scale + ")");
}
```

However, this method zooms the entire SVG graphic, including font sizes, graph edges, the line stroke-widths surrounding the nodes, etc.

Is it somehow possible *not* to zoom certain elements? The only solution I have seen so far is to put a line like this (took it from here http://jsfiddle.net/56RDx/2/)

```
node.attr("font-size", (nodeFontSize / d3.event.scale) + "px");
```

in the redraw method, to basically invert the zooming on certain elements on the fly. My problem is however (apart from this being an ugly hack), that my edge-widths are dynamically generated on graph-drawing (according to some graph properties...), so this 'invertion' method does not work...

Comment: Why not set `scale()` to a smaller amount on individual SVG shapes?

Comment: Do you have a demo and what are you trying to _not_ zoom?

Comment: @A.M.K The code is kind of huge, would be difficult to put that into a demo... But this here is the source of many of the used features: http://bl.ocks.org/2514276#index.html

Comment: @A.M.K How would I go about setting ''scale()'' to a smaller amount for only some SVG shapes?

Comment: Nevermind, that wouldn't work, please see my below answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. you can add a class to the element you want to trigger the zoom on:

   ```
   d3 ... .append('svg:g').classed("some_classname", true).call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw))...
   ```

   then do:

   ```
   function redraw() {
     trans = d3.event.translate;
     scale = d3.event.scale;
     vis.selectAll("some_classname").attr("transform", "translate(" + trans + ")" + " scale(" + scale + ")");
   }
   ```

   ---
2. or you can add a class to all elements you don't want to trigger the zoom on then use the CSS3 :not pseudo-class:

   ```
   function redraw() {
     trans = d3.event.translate;
     scale = d3.event.scale;
     vis.selectAll("*:not(.some_classname)").attr("transform", "translate(" + trans + ")" + " scale(" + scale + ")");
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I could find is an "ugly hack", if (I assume you are) you're trying to not zoom lines for example, the you should try the below, it works for both zooming in and out:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/gJMTb/

JavaScript:

```
function redraw() {
  vis.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
  vis.attr("font-size", (nodeFontSize / d3.event.scale) + "px");
  vis.selectAll("line.link").style("stroke-width", getStrokeWidth); // Function so it runs for each element individually
}

function getStrokeWidth(){
    if (!this.__data__.stroke) { // Doesn't exist, so set it to the original stroke-width
        this.__data__.stroke = parseFloat(d3.select(this).style("stroke-width"));
        // I found __data__ to be easier than d3's .data()
    }
    return this.__data__.stroke / d3.event.scale + "px";
}
```

Please see the [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-style) for details on using a function with `style()`

Comment: However, I'm not sure I really understand what's going on here... Inside the function `getStrokeWidth` the reference `this` points to the SVG line element, right? So the `\_\_data\_\_` property points to the actual data element (graph edge) added using D3. But what has this to do with stroke? Isn't stroke defined on the SVG element, rather than the data element?

Comment: Once you change the `stroke-width` value you can't multiply it by `d3.event.scale` because (`d3.event.scale`) it's not a relative value. So, I cache the original `stroke-width` value in the elements `__data__` object to run the calculations on later. You can use a `console.log()` on the values to see what's going on better.

Comment: Forgot to mention, `__data__` is what D3's `.data()` uses to store stuff so you can also retrieve it via `.data()`. But, that creates a few extra objects and doesn't make it any easier.

Answer (score 0):

In D3 v7, I was able to achieve what you are looking for with the following:

```
function redraw() {
  vis.attr("transform", "translate(1, 1) scale(1)");
}
```

Here, the `vis` element will remain the same size (scale is 1) and stay in a fixed position (x and y translation is 1) while the rest of the graphics zoom (handled elsewhere).