# Disable zoom on selected elements only

Tags: d3.js

I have a simple SVG which has the ability to zoom and pan.

What I want to do is to prohibit the zoom on certain elements only, but keep the pan, the elements must remain in relation to each others position.

So in the example below the red circle can pan and zoom but the blue circle should only pan - think map marker and the red circle is the earth for example

This is what I tried but had no effect:

```
zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
        .translate([0, 0])
        .scale(1)
        .scaleExtent([1.3, 10])
        .on("zoom", zoomed);

function zoomed() {
  map.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + 
    " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")")
}

svgWidth = 1890;
svgHeight = 932;

map = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr({
            "width": svgWidth,
            "height": svgHeight,
            "id": "svg"
        })
        .call(zoom)
        .append("g");

var circle = map.append("circle")
  .attr("cx", 100)
  .attr("cy", 100)
  .attr("r", 20)
  .attr("fill", "red");

var circle2 = map.append("circle")
  .attr("cx", 140)
  .attr("cy", 140)
  .attr("r", 20)
  .attr("fill", "blue")
  .on('mousedown.zoom', null); // <-- no zoom on this element
```

Is this possible with `D3`?

[Here's a fiddle showing the full SVG example](https://jsfiddle.net/studiotime/xce0momh/8/)

**UPDATE**

I've just noticed that Google maps has a similar thing - if you pinpoint a place (or several places) a marker(s) appears which stays (almost) the same size regardless of zoom but pans with the map. That's what I'm trying to achieve.

[I have seen this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916449), my question is not a duplicate as that stops panning as well, which I don't want

Comment: look up semantic zooming : http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3680957

Comment: Possible duplicate of [D3 selective Zoom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916449/d3-selective-zoom)

Comment: Could you also explain in more detail on what you want. Do you want the circle to stay the same size all the time even when zooming ? So basically the zoom doesn't effect the circle at all ? Or do you want to not be able to zoom when over the blue circle ?

Comment: @thisOneGuy Your first statement is correct - the blue circle stays the same size all the time but still pans with the whole svg - the red circle pans and zooms

Comment: I'm not sure what you want in general but in this case it looks like you can get the effect you want by just keeping the radius of the blue circle the right size: https://jsfiddle.net/xce0momh/1/. I think the solution that covers every case might be a little ad-hoc.

Comment: Thanks @mrmcgreg that works but doesn't - I've created a super simple example here as I always try to do, but the actual element I want to retain the size of is a complex path, not a circle

Comment: @DarrenSweeney The accepted answer to the "*duplicate*" question can easily be adjusted to fulfill your needs. You just have to apply translation alone to the blue circle and translation + scaling to the red circle. Have a look at the `zoomed()` function in this updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xce0momh/3/).

Comment: @altocumulus No, that doesn't work - put your mouse over the blue circle and zoom - it should stay where it is and the rest should zoom - look at this fiddle for better example - blue circle should stay where it is in relation to red - https://jsfiddle.net/studiotime/xce0momh/8/

Answer (score 0):

You need to negate the effects of the zoom on the target object whenever the UI zooms in:

```
function zoomed() {
  map.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + 
    " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
  d3.selectAll(".exclude-from-zoom").attr("transform", "scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}

/* ... */

var circle2 = map.append("circle")
  .attr("class", "exclude-from-zoom")
  .attr( ... /* do the rest, excluding the on() event call */
```

Comment: That doesn't work properly - have a look at this fiddle for better example https://jsfiddle.net/studiotime/xce0momh/8/ - blue circle should stay same size/position while red zooms